# Get position of Image from inside UIImageView to Window's Coordinate

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, cgrect

I have an imageView and its frame is `(47.0, 415.66666666666674, 320.0, 320.0)`, its y origin is `415`

```
lazy var imageView: UIImageView = {
   let imgView = UIImageView()
   // ...
   imgView.contentMode = .aspectScaleFit
}
```

To get the rect of the image inside that imageView I use:

```
view.layoutIfNeeded()

let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imageView.image!.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)

print(imageRect) // (-47.0, -358.2753623188407, 320.0, 205.21739130434787)
```

When I try to get convert the imageRect to find out where it is inside the Window's coordinate system I get

```
let frameInWindow = imageView.convert(imageRect, from: nil)

print(frameInWindow) // (-47.0, -358.2753623188407, 320.0, 205.21739130434787)
```

I have 2 questions:

1- why are the `x` and `y` values coming up as negative `-47` and `-358`

To get the positive y value I use `let yPosition = abs(frameInWindow.origin.y)` which gives me a yPosition of `358` however that is above the imageView's y position.

2- why is the yPosition not something like 425 or wherever it is at considering the center of the image is set at the center of the imageView and because the image is smaller than the imageView its y.origin should be below 415 (the imageView's y value inside the Window)

Answer (score 1):

When you say `imageView.convert(imageRect, from: nil)` you are converting the `imageRect` from the window's coordinates to the image view's coordinates. But the `imageRect` was not in the window's coordinates, so that makes no sense.

Comment: that makes sense but I can't do this: `let frameInWindow = imageView.image.convert(imageRect, from: nil)`

Comment: That's right. There is nothing to convert. An image is not a view.

Comment: but I do have the rect for the image, so how do I convert that rect to the window? `let imageRect = AVMakeRect(aspectRatio: imageView.image!.size, insideRect: imageView.bounds)`